# Does a subclass constructor require all arguments of superclass constructor?

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor

I have two classes, `Staff` and `AdvancedStaff`, which extends the former.

`Staff` has this constructor:

```
public Staff (String number, String title, String name, String role, char level) {
        staffNumber = number;
        staffTitle = title;
        staffName = name;
        staffRole = role;
        payScaleLevel = level;
    }
```

I'll note that all instance variables have been set to private.

While, `Advanced Staff` has this constructor:

```
public AdvancedStaff (String number, String title, String name) {
        super(number, title, name);
        role = "Entry level Advanced Staff"; 
        level = 'A';
    }
```

However, this throws a "symbol not found" error for my `Staff` constructor.

I've tried using `super.staffRole = "Entry level Advanced Staff";` but the private scope of my superclass prevents this.

I've found that adding the fields `String role` and `char level` to my `AdvancedStaff` constructor allows me to call the super constructor, but I'm wondering if there's a way to call the super constructor without passing all of its arguments in my subclass constructor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to provide all arguments to the constructor.

In your case, you still can call the constructor of `Staff`, but you **must** provide some default values, like so:

```
super(number, title, name, "Entry level Advanced Staff", 'A');
```

This does the same work as what you're already doing in the constructor for `AdvancedStaff`, only now it's the `Staff` class setting the values of the private variables, since you're passing it via the constructor.

On a side note, if you plan on accessing these private variables from a subclass, you should really make them `protected` instead.

Answer (score 1):

No, you have to provide all arguments to function/constructor

Answer (score 1):

You either need to take @WilliamGaul's advice or create a new constructor in the parent that only accepts the 3 arguments you want to pass in.  Which one to choose depends on the context.